# Whats going on with Mapinfo these days?

Tags: mapinfo

I have not touched Mapinfo for a good 2-3 years. (Think it was 7.5 back then, around the time it got aquired by Pitney Bowes)
I found it a great package, particularly with Vertical Mapper and utilising MapBasic to automate tedious tasks.

I would like to get an update on peoples recent experiences with the product.  I saw some nice screens of v10 where the interface looked a lot shinier.  Has it changed much over the past few years?

What about the web side of MapInfo, was it Map Extreme or something? I am pretty sure there are no similar web platforms like what ESRI offer (Silverlight/JS/etc) - Are there any plans to catch up on the web side of things?

Comment: No one mentioning Envinsa? Native support a biggy, MapXtreme not being developed properly, imo.

Comment: I am new for MapXtreme. I am developing my Application under MapBasic but wish to make it more professional way with more GUI. Can anyone guide me to find MapXtreme trainer for a day or 2? BR Joni

Comment: Ask questions in your own thread, rather as replies to old threads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MapInfo has progressed a far bit over the last couple of updates, well that depends what you would call progressed.  The most recent updates in 10.5 have brought Bing maps, and dockable panels to the UI, native read and write of kml and a few other things.  Functionality wise it's pretty much the same, so can't really say much there.

In terms of web, I would say ESRI rule this area.  MapXtreme isn't the greatest thing out there: poor documentation; code that makes you feel like you're using .NET v1.1 etc; not a very active developer community.  Progress seems slow in this area for PBBI, I don't see them making a very active role in keeping up with ESRI.

Of course this is all only my personal opinion.

Comment: I agree with Nathan,I'm a MapXtreme trainer in my company and sometimes I can't even find specific answers,codes and examples about MapXtreme.

Answer (score 7):

They have added native support for Oracle Spatial, PostGIS, SQL Server spatial etc. All at no extra cost. The user interface has also been updated somewhat with a better layer-control, many new functions, but generally it still looks the same.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about the  Oracle Spatial, PostGIS, SQL Server spatial.  That is properly the better things from the updates.

Answer (score 2):

I went to a natural resources user forum put on by Pitney Bowes lately.  I got the impression that Mapinfo will be marketed towards and developed for mining companies from now on, as they realised that ESRI was the industry standard for a lot of other industries.